# Questions posed by brand-new members that are abandoned

Tags: discussion

First post on meta so, if i'm "doin' it wrong", I apologize.

I wanted to ask about the handling of questions with the following conditions:

- Question raised by brand new member ( < 10 reputation? )
- Answers provided that address issue
- New member never bothers accepting an answer and closing the question

Could these be flagged for review to have an answer selected? I know it really only helps dole out reputation to people who answered, but I am just curious as to how these (and there seems to be quite a bit each day) questions get dealt with.

Comment: Have a look at this question and answers here to get a general impression. https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2684/15356 The mechanics work in general and shouldn't have to be **en**forced

Comment: @hot2use I'm so glad I didn't ask his question! My-oh-my... #roasted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the original author of the question can accept an answer.

If they decide not to accept an answer, that's OK.

We *prefer* people to accept an answer, but we can't enforce it, or select an answer for them. Besides which, I have personally had old answers 'accepted' *years* after I wrote them.

If the user is truly new to Stack Exchange *as a whole*, it can be useful to leave a temporary comment encouraging them to accept an answer (perhaps linking to the help centre as below).

Accepting an answer doesn't *close* the question; new answers can still be added at any time. (The new answer might even be 'better' in the eyes of the question author; this is why the answer marked as accepted can be *changed*).

Given a clear question with good answers, the site is already winning. The lack of a green tick on one of them does not mean all that much.

The votes from the wider community are a usually a better guide to answer quality than the green tick anyway.

See also:

[What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) (help centre)
[How to deal with abandoned questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250797)
[Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669)

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I appreciate your answer (and gave it the green tick ;)  )

Comment: @Wes Ha! Normally people fail to accept an answer on such questions purely for the irony value. Don't forget you can change the accepted answer at any time, in case a better one comes along.

Comment: I'm waiting for @BrentOzar to comment, then I'll RIP IT away from you and give it to him! jk.

Comment: @Wes Fine. Absolutely fine. Though as I understand it, Brent doesn't currently have the power to ban you from the site for upsetting him ;) *cough*

Comment: well crap. now I really have to weigh my actions... He does have the ability to shame me in hilarious fashion on his blog. Then again, so do you.

Comment: YOU CANNOT WIN.

Comment: That is what life seems to keep reminding me :D